# How to get the same output of floating point variables containing exact integral values from different versions of fmt library?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, floating-point, fmt

I wrote a program that uses `fmt` library to convert floating point values in text. And recently I found that its output is distinct depending on operating system for exact integers. For example, using `fmt` package from Ubuntu 20 zero value is printed as `0.0` and using `fmt` package from Ubuntu 22, the same value is printed as `0`.

As far as I see, the difference was introduced in between `fmt` v7.0.0 and v7.1.3.
This can be demonstrated using the simplified program as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/format.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << fmt::format( "{}", 0.0 );
}
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/d8W3EbGhM

I would like to have exactly the same output of numbers produced by both `fmt` package from Ubuntu 20 and from Ubuntu 22 (it can be either `0.0` or `0`, but the same on both). Is there a way to achieve this by some settings of `fmt` or by using some special format-string in place of `{}`, which does not limit the precision of output?

Comment: Try `std::format("{:.1f}", 0.0)`

Comment: @Peter, you suggest to limit precision to 1 digit after the decimal point (https://godbolt.org/z/zxojxx7TK), and I would like to print all values with maximum precision (and only standardize output for integers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `#` specifier to preserve the decimal point (and trailing zeros where appropriate). For example:

```cpp
std::cout << fmt::format("{:#}", 0.0);
```

prints "0.0" on both versions ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Kq6P5xfKv)).

Quoting the [release notes](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/releases/tag/7.1.0):

> Changed the default floating point format to not include `.0` for consistency with `std::format` and `std::to_chars`. It is possible to get the decimal point and trailing zero with the `#` specifier.

Answer (score 2):

They seemed to make a default format behavior for double type as it's `{:g}`, that removes all trailing zeroes. Hence, use it

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << fmt::format("{:g}\n", 0.0);  // outputs 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with `{:g}` is that it limits the precision to 6 digits after the decimal point, which I would like to avoid: https://godbolt.org/z/rf55Mrfsr

Comment: Use any precision you want, `{:.17g}` works well like `{}`.

Comment: Thanks. It works, however slightly changes output for some values: https://godbolt.org/z/cE169be8h And I guess that something like `{:.8g}` must be used for `float`s?